# Heroku environment causing Java/Nashorn/ReactJS application to crash

Tags: javascript, java, heroku, webpack, nashorn

Github repo https://github.com/damorton/dropwizardheroku-webgateway

Build `./gradlew stage`

Heroku application runs fine locally using `heroku local` after build and webpack phases, but crashes on the Heroku environment because the application cannot read the `bundle.js` file produced by the webpack stage of the build.

**Done so far**

- Logged into Heroku app using `heroku run bash` and checked if the `bundle.js` file was being created, it is.
- Updated `system.properties` to use a similar Java version as my local env `java.runtime.version=1.8.0_131`

**Heroku logs**

```
Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
2017-05-05T10:55:43.963570+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx350m -Xss512k -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
2017-05-05T10:55:45.617664+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO  [2017-05-05 10:55:45,613] org.eclipse.jetty.util.log: Logging initialized @1649ms
2017-05-05T10:55:45.696063+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO  [2017-05-05 10:55:45,695] io.dropwizard.server.SimpleServerFactory: Registering jersey handler with root path prefix: /
2017-05-05T10:55:45.696110+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO  [2017-05-05 10:55:45,695] io.dropwizard.server.SimpleServerFactory: Registering admin handler with root path prefix: /admin
2017-05-05T10:55:45.696230+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO  [2017-05-05 10:55:45,696] io.dropwizard.assets.AssetsBundle: Registering AssetBundle with name: assets for path /assets/*
2017-05-05T10:55:59.241010+00:00 app[web.1]: InputString in is null with path assets/js/bundle.js
2017-05-05T10:55:59.243502+00:00 app[web.1]: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
2017-05-05T10:55:59.243739+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:78)
2017-05-05T10:55:59.243867+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:72)
2017-05-05T10:55:59.243967+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.bitbosh.dropwizardheroku.webgateway.api.NashornController.read(NashornController.java:46)
2017-05-05T10:55:59.244023+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.bitbosh.dropwizardheroku.webgateway.api.NashornController.<init>(NashornController.java:27)
2017-05-05T10:55:59.244096+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.bitbosh.dropwizardheroku.webgateway.Main.run(Main.java:43)
2017-05-05T10:55:59.244149+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.bitbosh.dropwizardheroku.webgateway.Main.run(Main.java:23)
2017-05-05T10:55:59.244212+00:00 app[web.1]:    at io.dropwizard.cli.EnvironmentCommand.run(EnvironmentCommand.java:43)
2017-05-05T10:55:59.244255+00:00 app[web.1]:    at io.dropwizard.cli.ConfiguredCommand.run(ConfiguredCommand.java:85)
2017-05-05T10:55:59.244306+00:00 app[web.1]:    at io.dropwizard.cli.Cli.run(Cli.java:75)
2017-05-05T10:55:59.244391+00:00 app[web.1]:    at io.dropwizard.Application.run(Application.java:79)
2017-05-05T10:55:59.244436+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.bitbosh.dropwizardheroku.webgateway.Main.main(Main.java:26)
```

From the logs the application is throwing a `NullPointerException`
 and this is caused by the Nashorn engine in `NashornController.java` evalulating a `Reader` that was created from an InputStream of the `bundle.js` file.

What I cant figure out is why it works OK locally, but crashes on the Heroku environment. If I do not create the `bundle.js` file and evaluate the Javascript source code thats added to the bundle everything is working correctly.

Comment: Is the `bundle.js` inside of a JAR? Is it referenced with a full path?

Comment: @codefinger I'm using dropwizard so yes the `bundle.js` file should be packaged into a jar during the build/deployment stage of Heroku.

Comment: @codefinger The `bundle.js` file should be included in the deployment slug as its working and running fine locally using the same commands. `./gradlew stage && heroku local`

Comment: @codefinger Using a full path `src/main/resources/assets/js/bundle.js`causes an error because the Dropwizard configuration depends on an Assets bundle being initialised with the root of the assets directory as a parameter. This allows static files to be served from within the project directories, i.e. `assets/js/bundle.js`. This is present in `ApplicationConfiguration.java` in the repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem**

Heroku will run `./gradlew stage` if not using Spring Boot or Ratpack, this means developers need to specify what happens during their build in a `stage` task run by the platform. The tasks that `stage` depends on are not run in any predefined order. This results in the `webpack` task being run after `installDist`, building the Jar before `bundle.js` existed.

**Solution**

Define the order in which the tasks should run.

```
task stage(dependsOn: ['installDist', 'webpack', 'npmInstall', 'clean'])
npmInstall.mustRunAfter clean
webpack.mustRunAfter npmInstall
installDist.mustRunAfter webpack
```

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-gradle-apps-on-heroku#verify-that-your-build-file-is-set-up-correctly